# Node Red setInterval causing stale readings on redeploy

Tags: setinterval, node-red

I'm tinkering around with Node-Red and have made a my first simple custom node which adds to a counter each time an input is received.

The node also contains a call to `setInterval` which after ever 5 seconds calls `node.send()` with the counter value in the `msg.payload`.

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
  function MyNode(config) {

    RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
    var node = this;
    var count = 0;

    this.on('input', function(msg) {
        count++;
    });    

    setInterval(function() {

        var msg = 
        { 
            payload: { countTotal : count }
        };
        node.send(msg);
        return;

    }, 5000); // 5 Second Timer

  }
  RED.nodes.registerType("my-node", MyNode);
}
```

If I deploy the flow the node is behaving as expected.  However if I redeploy the flow I seem to be receiving two calls from the node.send().

One which is the correct value and the other is the last/stale value that was current before the redeploy.

For example:

**Deploy and click input 6 times before 5 seconds**

05 seconds: countTotal = 6

10 seconds: countTotal = 6

15 seconds: countTotal = 6

**Re-deploy and click input 3 times before 5 seconds**

05 seconds: countTotal = 3

05 seconds: countTotal = 6 [Old Stale reading]

If I restart node-red then it starts behaving as I'd expect.

**My questions**

Is this the correct approach to having a timer within a node, if not what should I be doing? If yes, why is the stale data coming through?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

Off the back off the answer from knolleary I've tried the following change

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
  function MyNode(config) {

    RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
    var node = this;
    var count = 0;

    var timer = setInterval(function() {    

        var msg = { payload: { countTotal : count }};
        node.send(msg);
        return;

    }, 5000); // 5 Second Timer

    this.on('input', function(msg) {
        count++;
    });  

    this.on('close', function(msg) {
        clearTimeout(timer);    
    });     

  }
  RED.nodes.registerType("my-node", MyNode);
}
```

...however now when a the flow is re-deployed, it completely stops!!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a timer each time a node is created, but at no time are you clearing the timer when the node is 'closed'. That is why you are getting multiple timers firing each time you deploy the node.

You need to add a handler for the `close` event, and tidy up any resources the node is using or has created - such as the timer.

http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-js#closing-the-node